# MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser vs. MCAdvertiserAssistant

Tags: objective-c, multipeer-connectivity

Can somebody explain my what is the difference beetween MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser  and MCAdvertiserAssistant?

Here in this [chat application](http://www.appcoda.com/intro-multipeer-connectivity-framework-ios-programming/) MCAdvertiserAssistant is used. In this [tutorial](http://nshipster.com/multipeer-connectivity/) MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser is used, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MCAdvertiserAssistant is a convenience class that handles advertising, presents incoming invitations to the user and handles users’ responses. This includes a user interface for handling invitations. That is basically an alert which says “Peer X wants to connect” (you can see the example in the chat app tutorial)

In the tutorial with the MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser they use their own proprietary logic to handle the invitation, in this case by presenting a UIActionSheet with 3 options (Reject, block, accept).

So, if you are happy with the way the MCAdvertiserAssistant works it is fine to use that one, it is simpler and requires less work. If you require more control you will need to use the MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a clear explanation in Apple's doc. See the Architecture section in 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCAdvertiserAssistant_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MCAdvertiserAssistant

I'll also quote in here:

> **Advertiser objects** (MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser) tell nearby peers that your app is willing to join sessions of a specified type.
>
> **Advertiser assistant objects** (MCAdvertiserAssistant) provide the same functionality as advertiser objects, but also provide a standard
>   user interface that allows the user to accept invitations. If you wish
>   to provide your own user interface, or if you wish to exercise
>   additional programmatic control over which invitations are displayed,
>   use an advertiser object directly.